# NoSuchFileException thrown while creating a symlink using Files.createSymbolicLink() method

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a created a gradle project [HERE](https://github.com/akmalick/symlink-demo-mcve) to experiment with the symbolic link creation. I have written a gradle task **runScript** that in turn executes a groovy script **myscript.groovy** that has the logic for symbolic link creation.

**NOTE :** **valid_symlink** branch makes use of  **SNIPPET 1** and **invalid_symlink** makes use of **SNIPPET 2**. So instead of uncommenting the SNIPPETS and running the task, you can just switch to respective branch and run the task.

**With SNIPPET 1 of myscript.groovy**

Whenever I try executing the task **runScript** by uncommenting the SNIPPET 1 in myscript.groovy(when in master branch) I can see that teh symlink is created successfully under the symlinkTEstFiles directory but the gradle build fails with below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\git-repos\test-cloning-symlink-demo-mcve\symlink-demo-mcve\..\..\..\symlinkTestFiles\toSymlink.groovy
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:585)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at myscript.run(myscript.groovy:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:428)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at myscript.main(myscript.groovy)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**With SNIPPET 2 of  myscript.groovy**

Running gradle task runScript by uncommenting SNIPPET 2(when in master branch) does not create  symlink and the build fails with below esxception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ..\..\..\symlinkTestFiles\toSymlink.groovy
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:585)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at myscript.run(myscript.groovy:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:428)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at myscript.main(myscript.groovy)
```

I am just not able to figure out the cause of exception. Whats wrong with my code ?
If I just execute the myscript.groovy, I do not get any exception and the symlinks are created in both cases i.e. SNIPPET 1 and SNIPPET 2. But the symlink created by SNippet 2 doesnot open.

Why does my groovy script runs fine when executed directly but throws exception when executed through gradle task.

Please guide me.

Comment: Try if file exists before creating link to it

Comment: @daggett as per the exception thrown java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ..\..\..\symlinkTestFiles\toSymlink.groovy,  its the symlink that the exception is complaining about not finding and not the original file. The original file that this symlink refers to exists under the src/main/groovy. The file path in exception message is the symlink's path not the original file's path. Do you still suggest to check for the existence of the symlink ? Is that required

Comment: then try to create a file in place of link.